# How do I use a custom js library in Spine.js?

Tags: spine.js

I know this seems simple, but I am trying to include a javascript library in my spine app for reference in my spine classes. Any ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spine documentation suggests [using Hem](http://spinejs.com/docs/hem) to manage JavaScript/CoffeeScript dependencies.

> Hem also allows you to specify static JavaScript libraries to include,
>   under the "libs" option:

```
{
  "libs": [
    "./lib/other.js"
  ]
}
```

Hem isn't strictly necessary, though.  You can include the library by explicitly using a `script` tag in your HTML.  Notice how `other.js` is referenced in this modified version of [`index.html`](https://github.com/maccman/spine.contacts/blob/master/public/index.html) from the [Spine Contacts demo](http://spine-contacts.herokuapp.com/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/application.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="/other.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQuery  = require("jqueryify");
    var exports = this;
    jQuery(function(){
      var App = require("index");
      exports.app = new App({el: $("#article")});      
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header"><h1>Spine Contacts</h1></header>
  <article id="article"></article>
</body>
</html>
```

Now any global-level objects or functions in `other.js` are immediately accessible from any JavaScript/CoffeeScript in your application.